# should we use <label> yo <output>momma</output></label>?

Tags: html

We currently report all our output using `<span>Vector <strong>42</strong></span>`.

It seems that the most HTML+ and accessible way to tell the browser the most about what's going on is to use `<label>Vector <output>42</output></label>`.

I can't find any verbiage forbidding that, and I will try a screen reader like orca to see how it reads that output. It should just work, right?

Comment: `label` allows [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content). This includes `output`.

Comment: tidy likes it too. What I mean is I can find where it's permitted, but not where it's recommended. It would seem that <label>ing your <output> would be a common use case.